# Access parent class from child class

Tags: javascript, class

```
    var config = {
        a: 'test',
        b: {
            c: // SOmeway to access config a value
        }
    }
```

IS there any way to access value from class b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those things is a class. They're objects.

No, there's no way to access `config.a` where you have `c:` in your code, all within the same object literal. You can do it after the fact:

```
var config = {
    a: 'test',
    b: {
    }
};
config.b.c = config.a;
```

Note that `config.b.c` will receive the *value* of `config.a`. If someone updates `config.a` later, `config.b.c` will not be updated.

If `c` were a *function*, you could access `config.a` from within it:

```
var config = {
    a: 'test',
    b: {
        c: function() {
           // You can use `config.a` here
        }
    }
};
```

There, each time you call `c`, you'll be using the *current* value of `config.a`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this i found it in search in for javascript

this.base or this.base()

Comment: There is no magic `base` thing in JavaScript. Answering with guesses is not a good idea on Stack Overflow. :-)